# Express Route Parameters not working in vercel

Tags: node.js, express, parameters, routes, vercel

I am working on an express project which is a URL shortener. I am generating a unique id and attaching it to the website as route parameters. E.g. https://shorturlme.vercel.app/some_code. It works fine in localhost, but when I try to host it on vercel it shows a page not found error.
Below is what I have done.

```
app.get("/:uid",(req, res)=>{
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader("Content-type","text/html");
    getURL(req.params.uid, res);
    
});
```

Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

It works fine on other hosting providers like railway, but not on vercel.
I am using vercel because railway projects are valid for only for 20 days free.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this: https://shadowsmith.com/thoughts/how-to-deploy-an-express-api-to-vercel

#### `vercel.json`

```
{
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "app.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
          "src": "/(.*)",
          "dest": "app.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Another article covering exactly that: https://syntackle.live/blog/how-to-create-and-deploy-an-express-js-app-to-vercel-ljgvGrsCH7ioHsAxuw3G/

And the official docs: https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel

> When we deploy a server (Express.js based application) within a Serverless Function, we are executing a full server implementation on each request. This is an anti-pattern, as Serverless Functions should serve one purpose.

Apparently an anti-pattern but I just to have a basic Express.js, without thinking too much how to re-architecture the entire thing.

Comment: the article https://syntackle.live/blog/how-to-create-and-deploy-an-express-js-app-to-vercel-ljgvGrsCH7ioHsAxuw3G/ has been updated with latest vercel configuration settings for `vercel.json`. Those above options are now not recommended by Vercel. see https://vercel.com/docs/projects/project-configuration#legacy